# What VPN server can I install on linux and connect to on Windows through its builtin VPN client?

Tags: vpn, home-server

Windows has builtin VPN capability, and I would like to avoid extra programs running to connect to my server's VPN.

What VPN server can be connected to through the builtin Windows VPN functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really given us enough information to answer your question properly (what Linux flavor you are using and what version of Windows you are using would both contribute to the answer we would give) but [I believe L2TP and PPTP are both VPN protocols that most modern Windows operating systems support](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/q-what-vpn-protocol-do-you-recommend-windows-7-clients) in the native VPN client ([further information on both can be found here in a comparative format](http://www.ibvpn.com/billing/knowledgebase/76/What-VPN-protocol-to-chose-.html)) and both have Linux server binaries.

I would recommend you look at using [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) if you have no prior Linux experience and follow either [a guide for setting up an L2TP server](http://www.slsmk.com/setup-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu/) or [a guide for setting up a PPTP server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp).

There are plenty of other guides out there for other Linux flavors such as Debian, CentOS etc also using other VPN protocols such as [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) - but I am fairly certain OpenVPN requires a third party application be installed on the client operating system.

Comment: PopTop, or `pptpd` is going to be the easiest of the two to install (and can be nicely administered by WebMin if you use that), but far less cryptographically secure than OpenS/WAN/l2tpd/pppd.  OpenVPN isn't too difficult (aside from understanding certificates) and is very secure but it does require a client to be installed on Windows.  The client is not difficult to install or use if you've created the right configuration file for it.

Comment: @ultrasawblade thanks for backing up my post. OP has edited his post - originally it was for a Linux server..